# How to revert Windows 10 audio quality to that of Windows 7?

Tags: windows-10, audio, windows-10-upgrade

I recently updated from Windows 7 to Windows 10 on the free update.  Ever since, the audio quality of 3rd party applications such as games and Spotify has been very poor.  However, all the windows 10 alert tones sound fine.  There are multiple questions and threads about this topic and a lot of people are having the same problem.  I have looked through some of these and tried a few: Disable Dolby Digital Plus Effects (not installed); realtek loudness equalizer (not possible as explained bellow); removing a certain Windows Update (it had not been installed).  I believe this is because I don't use the audio outputs built into the motherboard but instead use a USB going into a Focusrite Saffire 6 USB which then goes to a set of speakers.  Due to this fact when i go onto the Realtek HD audio manager there are no controls and I'm presented with this message `You are seeing a blank page because there are no audio devices plugged into the system.  To activate the GUI please plug an audio device in the system.`  So I was wondering if any has found a fix to this problem.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the Windows 10 compatible Realtek device drivers?

Comment: Hi Dan.  "none of the solutions worked for me"  Since we're not mind readers, please edit your question to include exactly what you've tried already, as well as the results you experienced.  Please also add the model of your Realtek sound adapter.  As a first step in troubleshooting, remove all the existing Realtek stuff, head to Realtek (or your computer's manufacturer) and get the latest Windows 10 compatible drivers for your sound adapter, and try those.

Comment: Added some things I have tried

Comment: @Dan13_ Please take the time to format your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as far as I can tell I have fixed it.  In the end i just uninstalled the Realtek HD audio drivers and then found the correct audio driver for my motherboard that was Windows 10 compatible on the internet then installed it, restarted and that seems to have fixed it.